# User input accepting str and int (python)

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to programming and trying to make the user input accept both integer and strings. I have tried the following coding.. but not sure where I am going wrong. Any suggestions?

```
    noAdults = input("Please enter the number of adults:")
    while noAdults.isalpha():
        print("Number must be valid and >= 0")
    if noAdults.isdigit() and noAdults < 0:
        print("Error")
        noAdults = input("Please enter the number of adults:")
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

I am guessing there is a ValueError because I have used the variable noAdults with isalpha and is making an error because it is in an int?

Comment: That current code isn't going to check again for the new `noAdults` if it's got a letter in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's throwing the exception before you handle the bad case of string inputs, it fails on the first line. You can check `isalpha()` before attempting the `int()`, or you can catch the `ValueError` exception.

To expand on [chepner's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23485866/2441252), with a few extra print lines to show you what is going on:

```
while True:
    noAdults = input("Please enter the number of adults:")
    try:
        noAdults = int(noAdults)
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid number")
        continue
    if noAdults >= 0:
        break
    else:
        print("Not greater than 0")

print(noAdults)
```

This is a fully working version in Python 3.

Comment: I tried to check isalpha() first before doing the int.. I got the is alpha to return the error message but I was unable to get the int to return.. still returned an error. I have updated my code.

Comment: You need to convert it to an `int` like in chepner's code.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Are you talking about the try method? noAdults= int(noAdults)

Comment: Yes, you're not converting it to a number.

Comment: Thank you. This works and does everything I want it to do. However, not sure I am allowed to use break. I will work on it. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to verify that the input string is valid integer before you can check if it is non-negative

```
while True:        
    noAdults = input("Please enter the number of adults:")
    try:
        noAdults = int(noAdults)
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid number")
        continue
    if noAdults >= 0:
        break
    else:
        print("Number must be >= 0")
```

Comment: This did work.. However it did not give the prompt message of "number must be valid.." when entering in a new number. I tried to add it in, but I'm so confused.

Comment: I haven't moved to Python 3 yet, so I'm still getting in the habit of using the `print` function instead of the `print` statement.